# Simple way to evaluate the double integration of sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + 1) limits x=0 to 1, y=0 to 1

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

To evaluate the integral, I performed the integration with respect to x and put the limits of x. I got this result:

$$\sqrt{y^2 + 2}/2 + (y^2 + 1) \ln(1+ \sqrt{y^2 + 2})/2 - (y^2 + 1)/2 \ln(\sqrt{y^2 + 1}) +c$$

Now I need to integrate the above expression with respect to y, which seems to be rather complex. Is there a simple way to evaluate the original integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, by symmetry, your integral equals
$$
2\int_0^1\int_0^x\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}\,dy\,dx.
$$
Changing to polar coordinates, you will get new limits
$$
0\leq \phi\leq \pi/4\quad\text{and}\quad 0\leq r\leq 1/\cos\phi,
$$
and so you end up with
$$
2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{1/\cos\phi}\sqrt{1+r^2}\,r\,dr\,d\phi.
$$
The inner integral is easily calculated,
$$
\int_0^{1/\cos\phi}\sqrt{1+r^2}r\,dr=\Bigl[\frac13\bigl(1+r^2\bigr)^{3/2}\Bigr]_0^{1/\cos\phi}=\frac{1}{3}\bigl(1+1/\cos^2\phi\bigr)^{3/2}-\frac{1}{3}.
$$
For the outer one, set $u=\tan\phi$, and you will have to tackle
$$
\int\frac{(2+u^2)^{3/2}}{1+u^2}\,du.
$$
Next, set
$$
s=\frac{u}{\sqrt{2+u^2}}
$$
and you will end up with a rational integrand,
$$
\int\frac{4}{(1-s^2)^2(1+s^2)}\,ds.
$$
I suppose you are now on safe ground? Continue with partial fraction decomposition. If I do not do too many errors in my calculations, the result is

> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{\pi}{18}+\frac{2}{3}\log(2+\sqrt{3})\approx 1.28.$$

Comment: Tried to do this on my own. How did you know we were supposed to put s = u/sqrt(2+u^2)?

Comment: It is close to the [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution), and I have just found that it works very well in expressions like this. I'm sorry, but I do not have a better reference than that.

Comment: Hmm, ok I understand. It's been several years since I last did calculus so that intuitive nature of knowing exactly what technique to use by just looking at the problem is gone :-) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

hint
:$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}dxdy$$ turn to polar coordinate 
$$x^2+y^2=r^2\\dxdy=rdrd\theta\\w.r.t [0,1]\times[0,1]\\\to 0\leq r\leq 1 \\0\leq \theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{9}^{\sec \theta}\sqrt{r^2+1}\times rdrd\theta$$

Comment: Using it I got this result: 0.957362. But when I evaluated the original integral in python, I got: 1.28078927. Also, how is dx dy = r dr dTheta?

Comment: @coolscitist :see this page ,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636021/rigorous-proof-that-dx-dy-r-dr-d-theta/1636057#1636057

Comment: Hmm got the r dr dTheta part. But still the two integrals are not giving same results when I did them in python.

Comment: @Khosrotash I think integral limits are incorrect!

Comment: $$\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}r \sqrt{r^2+1}dtdr=\frac{1}{6} \left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right) \pi$$
while
$$\int _0^1\int _0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}dydx=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{3}+\log \left(7+4 \sqrt{3}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi }{18}$$
Why?

Comment: $$\int _{\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^{\frac{1}{\sin\theta}}r \sqrt{r^2+1.}drd\theta +\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\int _0^{\frac{1}{\cos\theta }}r \sqrt{r^2+1.}drd\theta$$

Comment: You are right , I'll fix it .