# Completing Proof of Jacobian Determinant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, determinant, polar-coordinates, jacobian

I am actually trying to Prove the formula:
$$dxdy=rdrd\theta$$ When we change Cartesian System to Polar Coordinates:

We have:
$$x=r\cos \theta$$ So

$$dx=-r\sin \theta d\theta+\cos \theta dr$$

Like Wise:
$$y=r\sin \theta$$

$$dy=r\cos \theta d\theta+\sin \theta dr$$

Now we get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
dx\\ dy
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -r\sin \theta\\ 
 \sin \theta& r\cos \theta
\end{bmatrix} \times
 \begin{bmatrix}
dr\\ d\theta 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we call:

$$J=\begin{vmatrix}
\cos \theta &-r\sin \theta \\ 
 \sin \theta& r\cos \theta
\end{vmatrix}=r$$

But Now i could not prove:

$$dxdy=Jdr d\theta$$

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1636057/513870

Comment: The determinant is the area scaling factor of the linear transformation described by the matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can take determinants on both sides.
So you'll get,
$$ \det(dx dy) = \det(J)*\det(dr d\theta) = r*\det (dr d\theta) $$
Using the property of scalar multiplication for determinants,
$ \det(dx dy)=det(r*dr d\theta)$.
Now comparing respective elements in both determinants,
$dx=r*dr$ and $dy=d\theta$.
Hence, $dx*dy=r*dr*d\theta$.